# Why use "[*]" instead of "[]" in function prototype?

Tags: c, arrays, language-lawyer, c99

Here is what is it [written](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) as rationale for adding the fancy `*` star syntax for declaring array types inside function prototypes - just for clarification before we get into the question:

> A function prototype can have parameters that have variable length
>   array types (§6.7.5.2) using a special syntax as in 
>   `int minimum(int,int [*][*]);` This is consistent with other C prototypes where the name
>   of the parameter need not be specified.

But I'm pretty confident that we can have the same effect by simply using only ordinary arrays with unspecified size like this (here re-writing the function example named `minimum` given above in the quote with what I believe exactly the same functionality (except for using `size_t` instead of `int` as first parameter which isn't that important in the case)):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int minimum(size_t, int (*)[]);

int (main)()
{
    size_t sz;

    scanf("%zu", &sz);

    int vla[sz];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        vla[i] = i;

    minimum(sizeof(vla) / sizeof(*vla), &vla);

    int a[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };

    minimum(sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a), &a);
}


int minimum(size_t a, int (*b)[a])
{  
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(*b) / sizeof(**b); ++i)
        printf("%d ", (*b)[i]);

    return printf("\n");
}
```

Because I'm pretty sure that there was some place in the standard stating that 2 arrays are compatible only if their size are equal and no-matter if they are variable or not.

My point is also confirmed by the fact that the `minimum` definition wouldn't complain for "conflicting types" as it would if some of it's parameters had incompatible types (which I don't think is the case as both of those arrays have size which is unspecified at compile-time - I refer to the second parameter of `minimum`).

OK besides - can you point me 1 single use-case for `[*]` that can not be replaced using ordinary unspecified size arrays?

The above code compiles without any warnings using both clang and gcc. It also produces the expected output.

For anyone who doesn't know C (or anyone who thinks that he/she knows it) - function parameter of type array is implicitly transformed to "pointer to its elements type". So this:

```
int minimum(int,int [*][*]);
```

Gets adjusted to:

```
int minimum(int,int (*)[*]);
```

And then I'm arguing that it could be also written as:

```
int minimum(int,int (*)[]);
```

Without any consequences and with the same behavior as the 2 forms above. Thus making the `[*]` form obsolete.

Comment: `int (*)[]` is not a VLA. Which compiler error do you get? Did you try at least to compile? What is your point? Looks like some start of discussion. This is no discussion forum.

Comment: @Olaf I'm asking for a use-case where the star array syntax for function prototypes can not be replaced using ordinary array with unspecified size. And yes `int (*)[]` is not a VLA but what's your point?

Comment: There is no "star array syntax"! A pointer is not an array and vice versa. Learn the differences, there are enough questions about these basics.

Comment: @Olaf I know that I was referring to the syntax when VLA with unspecified size is declared inside function prototype. Better first read my whole question before ranting.

Comment: @n.m. I meant arrays which are not VM.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] what you mean. There is no working example with `[*][*]` in your code. If your compiler complains, read the standard **very carefully** again. (It follows the same correct logic like the conversion of an array to a "pointer to the first element" for a function argument.

Comment: @Olaf I believe everything that is needed is already in the question. The 'working' example with `[*][*]` (or rather `(*)[]`, `[][]` in the case) is already there and I'm just asking why would I ever want to use `[*][*]` or `(*)[*]` instead.

Comment: As I already wrote, `int (*)[]` is something very different than `int [*][]` or `int [*][*]`! You really confuse pointers and arrays. You don't show even the simplest proof by providing code for each variant which compiles.

Comment: The new question edited in under the "Conclusion" heading, should actually be posted as a new question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> OK besides - can you point me 1 single use-case for [*] that can not
>   be replaced using ordinary unspecified size arrays?

This would be the case, when you pass three-dimensional VLA array:

```
int minimum(size_t, int [*][*][*]);
```

This can be written as:

```
int minimum(size_t, int (*)[*][*]);
```

or even using an array of unspecified size:

```
int minimum(size_t, int (*)[][*]);
```

But you have no possibility to omit nor get around of the last indice, thus it has to stay as `[*]` in a such declaration.

Comment: `But you have no way to omit get around the of the last indice, so it has to stay as [*] in such declaration.` Can you clarify what you mean by that? The grammar is just off enough that I can't tell what you mean.

Comment: @callyalater: Edited, hopefully now it's better.

Comment: Much better. Thank you. That makes much more sense now.

Comment: @CisNOTthatGOODbutISOisTHATBAD, so to summarize, you are not interested in the answer to your own question.

Comment: @CisNOTthatGOODbutISOisTHATBAD, thanks for clarifying. It really didn't come accross.

Answer (score 6):

`[]` can only be used as the leftmost "dimension specifier" of a multidimensional array, whereas `[*]` can be used anywhere.

In function parameter declarations, the leftmost (only!) `[...]` is adjusted to `(*)` anyway, so one could use `(*)` in that position at the expense of some clarity.

One can omit the dimension in the next-to-leftmost `[...]`, leaving the empty brackets. This will leave the array element type incomplete. This is not a big deal, as one can complete it close to the point of use (e.g. in the function definition).

The next `[...]` needs a number or `*` inside which cannot be omitted. These declarations

```
int foo (int [*][*][*]);
int foo (int (*)[*][*]);
int foo (int (*)[ ][*]);
```

are all compatible, but there isn't one compatible with them that doesn't specify the third dimension as either `*` or a number. If the third dimension is indeed variable, `*` is the only option.

Thus, `[*]` is necessary at least for dimensions 3 and up.